# overlay the histograms by using the fill parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, fill

I would like to create a graphic to show how often each type of event is responsible for reducing each specie.

In total I have 9 species and 8 events. I would like to fix the events like different bars groups (fill) and the species on the x-axis like in the picture below.

I created the following script but I get this error message

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to do a correct script?
Thank you very much in advance

```
library(ggplot2)
event <- factor(Dataset, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",  "H"))
ggplot(Dataset) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=specie, fill=event), 
                 colour="grey50", alpha=0.5, position="identity")
```

**data**

```
Dataset <- structure(list(specie = structure(1:9, .Label = c("Hipp_amph", 
"Hipp_eq", "Phil_mont", "Pota_larv", "Red_aru", "Sylv_grim", 
"Sync_caf", "Trag_oryx", "Trag_scri"), class = "factor"), A = c(2.97029703, 
0, 13.86138614, 12.87128713, 0, 17.82178218, 2.97029703, 0, 0.99009901
), B = c(0, 7.920792079, 55.44554455, 51.48514851, 33.66336634, 
27.72277228, 33.66336634, 15.84158416, 62.37623762), C = c(0, 
5.940594059, 0.99009901, 8.910891089, 2.97029703, 0, 10.89108911, 
4.95049505, 21.78217822), D = c(0, 0, 0, 0.99009901, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), E = c(16.83168317, 28.71287129, 74.25742574, 100, 40.59405941, 
32.67326733, 89.10891089, 27.72277228, 86.13861386), F = c(6.930693069, 
0, 10.89108911, 42.57425743, 0, 0, 7.920792079, 0, 2.97029703
), G = c(0, 0, 0, 0.99009901, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), H = c(0, 4.95049505, 
1.98019802, 1.98019802, 15.84158416, 0, 19.8019802, 0, 1.98019802
)), .Names = c("specie", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that you are trying to pass a factor/character variable to x axis which in this case needs numeric values.

You could try the below with your dataframe and make a trellis with `specie`; either this or you sacrifice filling the bars with `event` (A, B, etc.), and put `specie` in `fill`.

Moreover, what is needed in the first place is to gather the data in a long format in order to be able to pass it to `aes`.

```
library(tidyverse)

Dataset <- Dataset %>% gather(event, value, 2:9)

ggplot(Dataset) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=value, fill=event), colour="grey50", alpha=0.5, position="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ specie)
```